# How to use variables with imaplib SINCE and BEFORE

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I am using imaplib to get the number of emails received in a mailbox on specific dates and it works great but I would like to take it further and use variables to select the date range (with SINCE and BEFORE) and print the number of daily emails received since a chosen starting date until today in a a loop.

However I am already getting a error message when replacing the BEFORE date with today's date variable:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

today = date.today()
tdate = today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")


obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)  
obj.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'password')  
obj.select('Inbox')     
('OK', ['50'])  
gmail_count = obj.search(None,'(SINCE "28-Aug-2020" BEFORE "tdate")') 
values = gmail_count[1][0]
replaced = values.decode("utf-8").replace(" ", ",")
replaced.count(",") + 1

error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you are trying to use `variable` values to select the date range of **SINCE & BEFORE**. Since the 2nd parameter of `obj.search()` accepts a string value just [format the string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) prior to passing in.

For example

You can set a formatted variable like so and pass the variable value in there

```
rangeVals = (SINCE "{}" BEFORE "{}").format("<Start-Date>,<End-Date>")
```

And then pass the variable as the parameter, like so

```
gmail_count = obj.search(None, rangeVals)
```

If the solution is unsuccessful, consider updating your error traces to the question.