# IMAPlib how to select only emails since a given date

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

With IMAPlib I am using:

```
self.m.select("Inbox") 
typ, mail = self.m.search(None, "(ALL)", f'(SENTSINCE {datesince})')
```

where:

```
datesince = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=self.timerange)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

print("Datesince:", datesince)
```

Gives:

Datesince: 08-Oct-2021

But in my log file I can see that all the following emails were dealt with, some are from previous dates way in the past, why is the since filter not precise?

This is how I loop through the emails:

```
typ, mail = self.m.search(None, "(ALL)", f'(SENTSINCE {datesince})')
    ids = mail[0]
    id_list = ids.split()
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
    oldest_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    countmail = latest_email_id - oldest_email_id + 1
    print("countmail:", countmail)

    for self.i in tqdm(range(latest_email_id, oldest_email_id - 1, -1)):
        print("Incrementation:",self.i)
        typ, x = self.m.fetch(str(self.i), '(RFC822)')
```

I expunge deleted emails only after the loop.

Iterating over all mails to extract NAVs
countmail: 16
Incrementation: 265
subject: Amundi CDA Abs RTN MLT-STRGY Fund (ARMS) - 10082021 ****price delay****
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 22:10:34 +0000
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 264
subject: TR: Cashoutflow 01110066S03, DeAM-Fonds ENPT CORP
**Date: Thu, 7 Oct 2021 11:29:46 +0200**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 263
subject: R: ALIFOND: OUTFLOW
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 16:21:30 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 262
subject: RE: ONBOARDING - PF92671 – BOK GLOBAL DEVELOPED MARKETS FIXED INCOM  - LAUNCH DATE 08/10/2021
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 16:19:51 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 261
subject: RE: ONBOARDING - PF92671 – BOK GLOBAL DEVELOPED MARKETS FIXED INCOM  - LAUNCH DATE 08/10/2021
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 14:58:31 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 260
subject: RE: STANLIB IM ADVICE - CreLiq_Amundi-MM Global Bond - 06/10/2021
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 12:50:06 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 259
subject: RE: September 30,2021 NAV AM-MY EURO CREDIT FUND Not received
Date: Fri, 8 Oct 2021 12:01:27 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 258
subject: RE: Problème perf daido
**Date: Thu, 7 Oct 2021 17:34:51 +0200**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 257
subject: NAV officielle PF82299 Mirae - intégration PAMS
**Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 11:19:41 +0100**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 256
subject: NAV officielle PF82299 Mirae - intégration PAMS
**Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 11:19:41 +0100**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 255
subject: RE: ONBOARDING - PF90548 – CAVOM OBLIGATIONS INTERNATIONALES  - LAUNCH DATE 06/10/2021
**Date: Wed, 6 Oct 2021 13:22:53 +0200**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 254
subject: RE: Aged claim !!- LU3503 DVD query ISIN: SE0000115446 ex date 30/06/2021 Account: 373662 -- Claim #186735 --- 1053736620W [AS3PAM-MAS-13894]
**Date: Thu, 7 Oct 2021 03:04:26 +0000**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 253
subject: FW: Trade FX Settlement Query -LU3510 Monnet -373669
Date: Tue, 28 Sep 2021 13:51:08 +0200
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 252
subject: RE: Devises - Desjardins + Desjardins Pooled Fund State Farm & TPIC Pension Plan September 2021
**Date: Wed, 29 Sep 2021 14:23:09 +0200**
Mail not deleted
Incrementation: 251
subject: ONBOARDING - PF90548 – CAVOM OBLIGATIONS INTERNATIONALES  - LAUNCH DATE 06/10/2021
**Date: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 13:48:26 +0200**
/home/ludo915/automate_PDP_IMAP/attachments/Onboarding Form CAVOM Obligations Internationales.xlsx
/home/ludo915/automate_PDP_IMAP/attachments/CAVOM_Obligations_Internationales_2021-09-30_1630583721207.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables with imaplib SINCE and BEFORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724964/how-to-use-variables-with-imaplib-since-and-before)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes @Vladimir thank you, although I am getting a few emails way in the past, outside the SINCE boundaries, I believe this is due to maternity leaves and people on holidays turning off their computers, and being part of a given mailing list, coming back to work & switching back on their outlook.

Answer (score 0):

It is precise. IMAP allows you to search for email both by arrival date at the recipient's server and by the sender's stated date. As [you can see from the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-52) the relevant keys are `since` and `sentsince`.

Comment: Why am I retrieving emails with dates prior to 08/10/2021 then?

Comment: Maternity Leaves? And people on holidays with unsent mails on their outlook mailboxes?

Comment: You probably want the SINCE key, and since IMAP is not timezone aware you may get up to 23 hours or 23 hours less than what you expect.

Comment: @Max ok but I am getting an email from Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 11:19:41 +0100 this is almost exactly 9 months ago, is there a logical explanation for this? I will try the SINCE key and solve this post if it works as expected.

Comment: Look at the `internaldate` value you can retrieve via IMAP, it's what's used. It is usually a second or so after the last date mentioned in a `Received` header field, but an IMAP client can set it to any date (using the `append` command).